# R sentiment analysis; 'lexicon' not found; 'sentiments' corrupted?

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to follow [this](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/sentiment-analysis-R) on-line tutorial on sentiment analysis.  The code:

```
new_sentiments <- sentiments %>% #From the tidytext package
  filter(lexicon != "loughran") %>% #Remove the finance lexicon
  mutate( sentiment = ifelse(lexicon == "AFINN" & score >= 0, "positive",
                         ifelse(lexicon == "AFINN" & score < 0,
                                "negative", sentiment))) %>%
  group_by(lexicon) %>%
  mutate(words_in_lexicon = n_distinct(word)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Generates the error:

```
>Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
>Evaluation error: object 'lexicon' not found.
```

Related, perhaps is that to me it appears the "sentiments" tables are acting strangely (corrupted?).  Here is a head of 'sentiments':

```
> head(sentiments,3)
>  element_id sentence_id word_count sentiment                                  
> chapter
> 1          1           1          7         0 The First Book of Moses:  
> Called Genesis
> 2          2           1         NA         0 The First Book of Moses:  
> Called Genesis
> 3          3           1         NA         0 The First Book of Moses:  > 
> Called Genesis
>                                  category
> 1 The First Book of Moses:  Called Genesis
> 2 The First Book of Moses:  Called Genesis
> 3 The First Book of Moses:  Called Genesis
```

If I use Get_Sentiments for bing, AFINN or NRC, though, I get what looks like an appropriate reponse:

```
>  get_sentiments("bing")
> # A tibble: 6,788 x 2
>   word        sentiment
>   <chr>       <chr>    >   1 2-faced     negative 
> 2 2-faces     negative 
> 3 a+          positive 
> 4 abnormal    negative
```

I tried removing (remove.packages) and re-installing tidytext; no change in behavior.  I am running R 3.5

Even if I am completely misunderstanding the problem, I would appreciate any insights anyone can give me.

Comment: I see that error when I use `stats::filter` instead of `dplyr::filter`. Perhaps `library(dplyr)` would help?

Comment: Thank you, but the DPLYR library is in the code. I explicitly declared it and ran the code right after, but no go.    I was kind of hoping the problem was DRLIB, though not actively used in this code, which I can't install because I get a message saying there's no version available for 3.5!

Comment: So I was mistaken, that error is slightly different, sorry about that. The `filter_impl` error might be because `sentiments` is not a `data.frame` **or** it does not have a column named `lexicon`. What does `str(sentiments)` look like?

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine with dplyr and tidytext loaded and gives the expected output. Try restarting your R-session and try the code again.

Comment: >Classes ‘sentiment’, ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  104880 obs. of     6    variables:
     $ element_id : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 7 8 9 ...
     $ sentence_id: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
    $ word_count : int  7 NA NA 10 NA 12 5 11 1 NA ...
 $ sentiment  : num  0 0 0 0.253 0 ...
 $ chapter    : chr  "The First Book of Moses:  Called Genesis"  $ category   : chr  "The First Book of Moses:  Called Genesis" (***this repeats****) - attr(*, "sorted")= chr  "element_id" "sentence_id"
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 - attr(*, "sentences")=<environment: 0x000000000d8c2fe8>

Comment: Tried running from R directly rather than R-Studio.  Saw this message:The following object is masked _by_ ‘.GlobalEnv’:

    sentiments
Am guessing that is part if not all of the problem.  How to fix?

Comment: Solved the problem with rm(sentiments)

Comment: how did you solve it by removing sentiments??

Answer (score 2):

The following instructions will fix the `new_sentiments` dataset as shown in the [Data Camp tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/sentiment-analysis-R).

```r
bing <- get_sentiments("bing") %>% 
     mutate(lexicon = "bing", 
            words_in_lexicon = n_distinct(word))    

nrc <- get_sentiments("nrc") %>% 
     mutate(lexicon = "nrc", 
            words_in_lexicon = n_distinct(word))

afinn <- get_sentiments("afinn") %>% 
     mutate(lexicon = "afinn", 
            words_in_lexicon = n_distinct(word))

new_sentiments <- bind_rows(bing, nrc, afinn)
names(new_sentiments)[names(new_sentiments) == 'value'] <- 'score'
new_sentiments %>% 
     group_by(lexicon, sentiment, words_in_lexicon) %>% 
     summarise(distinct_words = n_distinct(word)) %>% 
     ungroup() %>% 
     spread(sentiment, distinct_words) %>% 
     mutate(lexicon = color_tile("lightblue", "lightblue")(lexicon), 
            words_in_lexicon = color_bar("lightpink")(words_in_lexicon)) %>% 
     my_kable_styling(caption = "Word Counts per Lexicon")
```

The subsequent graphs will work too!

Answer (score 1):

It appears `tidytext` had to be changed, which broke some of the code in the tutorial.

To make the code run, replace

```r
new_sentiments <- sentiments %>% #From the tidytext package
  filter(lexicon != "loughran") %>% #Remove the finance lexicon
  mutate( sentiment = ifelse(lexicon == "AFINN" & score >= 0, "positive",
                              ifelse(lexicon == "AFINN" & score < 0,
                                     "negative", sentiment))) %>%
  group_by(lexicon) %>%
  mutate(words_in_lexicon = n_distinct(word)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

with

```
new_sentiments <- get_sentiments("afinn")
names(new_sentiments)[names(new_sentiments) == 'value'] <- 'score'
new_sentiments <- new_sentiments %>% mutate(lexicon = "afinn", sentiment = ifelse(score >= 0, "positive", "negative"),
                                                     words_in_lexicon = n_distinct((word)))
```

The next few graphs won't make as much sense (since we now only use one lexicon), but the rest of the tutorial will work

**UPDATE** [here](https://juliasilge.com/blog/sentiment-lexicons/)'s an excellent explanation from the `tidytext` package author as to what happened.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar problem, I try this code below, 
I hope it would help

```
library(tm)
library(tidyr)
library(ggthemes)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
library(textdata)

# Choose the bing lexicon
get_sentiments("bing")
get_sentiments("afinn")
get_sentiments("nrc")

#define new
afinn=get_sentiments("afinn")
bing=get_sentiments("bing")
nrc=get_sentiments("nrc")

#check
head(afinn)
head(bing)
head(nrc)
head(sentiments) #from tidytext packages

#merging dataframe
merge_sentiments=rbind(sentiments,get_sentiments('bing'),get_sentiments('nrc'))
head(merge_sentiments) #check

merge2_sentiments=merge(merge_sentiments,afinn,by=1,all=T)
head(merge2_sentiments) #check

#make new data frame with column lexicon added
new_sentiments <- merge2_sentiments
new_sentiments <- new_sentiments %>% 
  mutate(lexicon=ifelse(sentiment=='positive','bing',ifelse(sentiment=='negative','bing',ifelse(sentiment=='NA','afinn','nrc'))))

colnames(new_sentiments)[colnames(new_sentiments)=='value']='score'

#check
head(new_sentiments)
```