# Additional information to ensure R code will run on another computer?

Tags: r

`sessionInfo()` includes very useful info that will improve the chances of someone being able to run your code on their machine, including

- OS and version
- R version
- Attached packages

What other info can be provided with an R script to ensure someone else will be able to run it in their environment?

**NB** please include how to get that info (i.e. what command to run or where to look for it)

Comment: "It depends". In general code does work on all versions.  More specifically, old(er) code tends to work on new(er) versions as features tend to get added, not removed.  If and when that is different, versioned depends (ie "Depends: R (>= 3.5)") help.  But in short, your question lacks specifics to say more.

Comment: Are you building a package or simply a script that will be use on other computers? Anyway, the base ``sessionInfo()`` function should give you the most important informations. Take note that some packages require aditionnal things like an updated Java version.

Comment: (I agree with Dirk.) If you are doing something unusual which is likely to make this an issue, your best bet is probably a Docker image containing everything. Anyway, output of `extSoftVersion()` might be useful.

Comment: For Windows, it is also helpful to know what versions of RTools and MikTeX are installed in the system.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I was doing [this](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/sentiment-analysis-R) tutorial and had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127671/r-sentiment-analysis-lexicon-not-found-sentiments-corrupted/57847577#57847577) issue. I'm pretty sure some data may have been removed from a package due to unfortunate copy-write reasons, so the tutorial 'broke'. There's no reference to the package version used so it's hard(er) to search for the older version (especially when it's not in the archives). This is just an example (although `sessionInfo()` would be ample here)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I am trying to future proof by always running some quick/easy function to store necessary info along with a script/markdown. Just wondering if `sessioninfo()` does the job or if I should be delving deeper. I like Roland's idea of docker but that's a heavy weight solution (arguably mine is too, but storing some text is quite fast/easy relative to a docker build)

Comment: @slava-kohut thanks, do you know how to get those from within R?

Comment: This is a *very* loaded topic and cannot be answered in a comment, or even single answer.  Maybe start here:  https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ReproducibleResearch.html  But you can spend a lifetime making this waterproof.  (I.e. I have been doing in the space of Debian packages, and that is both easier as it is only one OS and harder as we have 12 hardware platoform and are perfectionists).  Doing it well across OSs is hard.  Which is why many of use Docker for these things.  "It. All. Depends."  And the specifics lacked in your question.  Good luck.

Comment: @user5783745 `shell('pdflatex --version')` and `devtools::find_rtools(debug = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a complete answer, I tend to include this function with scripts I send along as it will download a package if the computer does not have it. This is more of a suggestion for scripts. For packages, you can explicitly put what versions of other packages your package depends on.

```
package_load<-function(packages = NULL, quiet=TRUE, 
                       verbose=FALSE, warn.conflicts=FALSE){

  # download required packages if they're not already

  pkgsToDownload<- packages[!(packages  %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
  if(length(pkgsToDownload)>0)
    install.packages(pkgsToDownload, repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org", 
                     quiet=quiet, verbose=verbose)

  # then load them
  for(i in 1:length(packages))
    require(packages[i], character.only=T, quietly=quiet, 
            warn.conflicts=warn.conflicts)
}

## Example of use

package_load(c('dplyr', 'rgdal'))
```

This is helpful for one off scripts as it gets over the hurdle of a different computer not having the appropriate packages. However, I generally suggest to folks to make sure their version of `R` is up to date as well.

Is this the best solution? Probably not, but it does help with minor scripts you send along to others. For a larger code base, it would probably be better to put together a package or a docker image.

Answer (score 0):

I think the criterion you listed are the "basics" of reusability of a script. The next levels would be the possible interaction of your scripts (e.g. R Shiny scripts will use web features: therefore, giving the web browser and its version used to produce the script is a good practice). Also, another kind of information would be commentaries precising the expected input and outputs. 
NB: I would precise "attached packages and their versions", just for us to be sure...